# Do I always need to send full product data to Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

When I send the full product data to Google Analytics in the first event E1, do I still need to send compete product data in subsequent events E2, E3,... related to that product?

So, to be more concrete, let's say I send following product data to Google Analytics when the user sees the product on the page (product impression):

```
ga('ec:addImpression', {
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel/T-Shirts',   // Product category (string).
  'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
  'variant': 'Black',               // Product variant (string).
  'list': 'Search Results',         // Product list (string).
  'position': 1,                    // Product position (number).
});
```

Now what will happen if I only send product id in subsequent events related to that product:

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {
  'id': 'P12345'
});
```

Will Google Analytics find the product data created by the impression by product ID and "join" the product data? Or those two events will be connected to two separate products and the second event will be missing all the product data (e.g. I won't be able to filter that event by product category)?

Is that behaviour documented anywhere in Google Analytics documentation?

Comment: Enhance Ecommerce it's a little bit tricky, The only mandatory parameters are the ID/name, you have to add at least one of them (you're doing that)

The best documentation that you can get is this one, about the processing there is not so much documentation, experience/test is the best friend:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce